# Geneva Train Station to Geneva Airport (Air France Departures)

Tags: geneva, gva

My husband and I are traveling on Dec 26 from Gstaad to Geneva via Swiss Rail. We get in at 1:39pm at the Geneva Train station. From there we will rush to the Geneva Airport to check luggage, get through security and try to catch a 3:05pm Air France flight to Paris.

This gives us approx 1 hour 20 minutes. Is this enough time? If not, we can take a later flight, at 4pm. We have not booked our airline tickets yet.

Your advice is appreciated as we do not know the layout of the train station and airport.

Comment: What is the luggage check deadline for your Air France flight?

Comment: Good question - hadn't thought of that but I do believe for Int'l flights it's 30 minutes prior to take off. I think I just answered my own question!

Comment: I checked on [Air France](https://www.airfrance.fr/FR/en/common/guidevoyageur/aeroport/enregistrement_hle.htm#check-in-deadline). For departure from Europe (excluding metropolitan France) to a non-France location in Europe, it says 40 mins.

Comment: If I got that right, you have 46 minutes from scheduled rail arrival to check-in deadline.

Comment: Do you normally do lots of running? If not, I would book the later flight, and have a leisurely walk. And what if your train is late?

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question whether you mean Geneva station or Geneva airport station. You should definitely go to the latter, your train will stop at both.

Answer (score 4):

Your train arrives at 1:39pm at **Geneva Airport Station**, not Geneva station (it will have stopped at Geneva station 9 minutes earlier).

[image]

The Geneva Airport station is right next to the airport. The only difficulty is that the train station is connected to the arrivals level, when you want to go the check-in level (the french sector, actually). But that adds only a few minutes to get to an escalator or lift.

All in all, it should take you less than 10 minutes to get from the train to the check-in counter.

It's unclear whether the check-in deadline for Air France flights from Geneva to CDG is 30 or 40 minutes (depends whether they consider it a french airport, which it is, or not). So, worst case, you would need to have dropped your bags at 2:25pm for the 3:05pm flight. That means you have about 35 minutes margin.

So it's indeed perfectly doable, but does not leave any margin in case of a problem. I know Swiss trains are very, very punctual, but still...